# printing a set containing strings on graphics.h in c++

Tags: c++, string, bgi

I am trying to print the elements of a set containing strings on graphics.h console using outtext() function,but i get this error:

cannot convert 'std::string {aka std::basic_string}' to 'char*' for argument '1' to 'void outtext(char*)'|

this the piece of code that gives error:

```
for(i=0;i<20;i++){

    for(j=0;j<20;j++){

        outtext(str[i][j]);
    }
    
}
```

the template for the outtext function in the graphics.h header is like this:

```
void outtext(char *textstring);
```

i have used c_str() like this:

```
for(i=0;i<20;i++){

    for(j=0;j<20;j++){

        outtext(str[i][j].c_str());
    }
    
}
```

but this time it gives this error:

error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]|

Comment: What's `graphics.h`? That's not a c++ standard header.

Comment: What is the type of `str` in the code?

Comment: it is string str[20][20];

Comment: ok, c_str() return a `const char*` (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/). So change the prototype to `void outtext(const char *textstring);` (you won't able to make any change for textstring). OR you should copy it to another char* variable before put it through the function.

Comment: graphics.h was an old DOS graphics header which provided an API for Borland's old BGI graphics library, back in the 80s/90s. Nobody outside India has used it for the past 20 years or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this one as well:

```
char *cstr = new char[21]; // just in case string length is maxed at 20, leave 1 character for '\0'

for (int i = 0; i<20; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j<20; j++) {
        strcpy_s(cstr, str[i][j].length() + 1, str[i][j].c_str());

        outtext(cstr);
    }
}

delete[] cstr;
```

Just added a `char*` string to temporarily hold the converted `std::string` value. The tricky part is that `char*` strings normally have the terminating character `\0` which `std::string` don't have, so you have to add 1 more character to the size of each "row" of `str`.

Answer (score 1):

I take it this question is about the 30 years old BGI graphics library and Borland C++. The root of the problem is that this library was poorly written, as it didn't implement const correctness.

The Turbo C++ compiler did not follow anything remotely close to any C++ standard, so you are mostly out of luck. If you had a proper C++ compiler you could use `const_cast`, but I very much doubt this is available to you.

The only solution left is the dirty, bad way:

```
outtext((char*)str[i][j].c_str()); // bad practice
```

You should never cast away `const` like this in neither C nor C++.

Comment: I don't know which is sadder; that you know what the BGI library was on-sight of that header file, or that I did as well. Good grief I'm getting old. I actually *used* that thing on multiple occasions.

Comment: @WhozCraig Actually, schools were still using this for teaching in the late 90s, when DOS was still used. For some reason unknown, it is still popular in bad schools around India, where they think it is a mighty fine idea to teach students pre-standard C++ in the year 2016.

Comment: @Lundin My first (and thankfully only) exposure to BGI programming was on several projects I consulted on using Turbo C 2.0 (which, for its time, was a stellar compiler, integrated debugger and IDE, etc). That its immediate successor, Turbo C++ is *still* used today in a world with clang and gcc freely available just floors me.

Comment: @user6207597 let's not get ahead of ourselves. It *worked*. It is anything-but-perfect (and this answer amplifies why, and is worthy of your selection and upvote).

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the prototype of the output function then it is better to change `void outtext(char *textstring);` to void `outtext(const char *textstring);` because there is no need for the output function to modifiy the string. Otherwise you could use `const_cast` before passing to the function like `outtext(const_cast<char*>(str[i][j].c_str()))` or copy the string to another `char*` and passed the copied value.